# How can I use a chart in bootstrap from information in a database?

Tags: c#, html, database, bootstrap-4

I am making a Survey, which pushes the results into a database in Bootstrap and ASP.Net Core. How can I make a pie chart or a bar graph using this information? Is this possible?
Thanks So much.
--McIntyrelr20

Comment: Yes it is possible, and quite common.  You return a result set from the backend (ASP.Net Core) to the frontend, and populate the graph using that data.  This can be done in the view with the data from the view model.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It is best to break down the task into smaller achievable goals.  We do not know your skill level with these different technologies.  You may want to check out some tutorials on W3schools, YouTube, or other online resources first.  I would love to help, but the lack of information and effort makes it difficult.